# Get the max. value in List of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes.

```
public class PriceDetails 
{
  public float AverageNightlyRate { get; set; }
}

public class RoomContainer
{
  public PriceDetails RoomPriceDetails { get; set; }
  public string PromotionDescription { get; set; }
}    

public List<RoomContainer> HotelRooms { get; set; }
```

The list **HotelRooms** has 10 items.
I want to find the maximum value of  **AverageNightlyRate**.

I am using for loop to iterate .
Can I do it in an efficient manner ?

Comment: A `for` loop _is_ efficient.

Comment: Linq is the efficient way.

Comment: No, LINQ will perform at least as much work as a `for` loop in this case, and has additional overheads in setting up. Less code != more efficient.

Comment: @palakmehta: Efficient can mean to work more efficient or to create code that is more maintanable or readable, hence less prone of errors. If that is the meaning of _efficient_, you are right, Linq can increase efficiency. But not in terms of milliseconds.

Comment: Depending on your definition of "efficiency" ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343284.aspx):

```
var maxAverageRate = HotelRooms.Max(r => r.RoomPriceDetails.AverageNightlyRate)
```

---

If `RoomPriceDetails` could be `null`, then:

```
var maxAverageRate = HotelRooms.Where(r => r.RoomPriceDetails != null)
                               .Max(r => r.RoomPriceDetails.AverageNightlyRate);
```

Or

```
var maxAverageRate = HotelRooms.Select(room => room.RoomPriceDetails)
                               .Where(price => price != null)
                               .Max(price => price.AverageNightlyRate);
```

Comment: You have not taken PriceDetails and RoomContainer  class into consideration

Comment: @palakmehta that's because you have edited question. Anyway, see updated answer

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky :nopes.. @vcsjones has formatted the question and I thank him for it.

Comment: @palakmehta OK, anyway - I didn't see full code before that format. Now I see it, and you have complete answer :) BTW is it possible that RoomPriceDetails will be null?

Comment: It would be great , if we can take that into consideration.

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky  : I am getting teh below mentioned error :(
Error 33 'System.Collections.Generic.List< RoomContainer>' does not contain a definition for 'Max' and no extension method 'Max' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<RoomContainer>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @palakmehta are you using .NET 2.0?

Comment: Then just add `using System.Linq;` at the top of file

Comment: @lazyberezovsky : the property is AverageNightlyRate not AverageNinghtlyRate

Comment: @lazyberezovsky  :Thanks a lot for solving it and apologies for being so naive.Will continue improving it.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky  :I have added a property PromotionDescription  in RoomContainer class.I want to get the value of PromotionDescription  corresponding to the max. value of AverageNightlyRate.
Thanks

Comment: Data is bulky and for loop is gonna take a lot of time. Linq would be of great help .

Comment: @palakmehta if you are not using Linq to Sql or Linq to Entities, then you anyway need to loop over all items (either in foreach or for loop). In terms of performance there will be no gain with Linq. Linq just more readable in this case.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky :Definitely, I am using LINQ to sql.

Comment: Then definitely use Linq. Query will be executed on server side - big performance gain in this case

Comment: @lazyberezovsky :The solution taht yo gave would give me max value.I want to get the value of the PromotionDescription instead of max. value.

Answer (score 3):

```
HotelRooms.Max (r => r.RoomPriceDetails.AverageNightlyRate );
```

Comment: Just 3 minutes too late ;)

Answer (score 2):

When using `Min()` or `Max()`it is good to keep in mind that your design may want to consider implementing `DefaultIfEmpty().` If the `.Where` clause eliminates all elements we'll receive *'Sequence contains no elements'* error when calling `Min()` or `Max()`.

Instead of calling Min or Max directly on the collection returned by our `Where` statement, we can `Select()` the property list we are interested in. Then we can slip in `DefaultIfEmpty`. Calling `Min()` or `Max()` on `DefaultIfEmpty` ensures us a collection to work with.

```
var maxRate = HotelRooms.Where(r => r.RoomPriceDetails != null)
                        .Select(r => r.RoomPriceDetails.AverageNightlyRate)
                        .DefaultIfEmpty() // Now even if our where causes an empty selection list we will return DefaultIfEmpty.
                        .Max(); // Now we always have a gaurenteed value for max.
```