# How to find biggest value of a public int in a public class?

Tags: c#

I have a public class Lesson : Imodel it has a public int OrderNUm. How can I say out of all the lessons what is the highest value for OrderNUm Another explanation say i have 5 boxes with different amount of sweets i want to know the value of the highest amount of sweets out of all the boxes

I have tried this but it clearly didn't work

```
[HttpPost]
        [AuthorizeAdmin]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateLesson(LessonBindingModel model)
        {
            //Validate model

            //if (!ModelState.IsValid) { Debug.WriteLine("Invalid"); return View("CreateLesson", model); }

            //Populate model

            model.Lessons.Max(x => x.OrderNum);

            //Commit model.
            await _LessonService.Commit(model.Lesson);

            
            //Return to Course
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Course", new { Category = model.Course.Category, id = model.Course.id  });
        }
```

```
public class Lesson : IModel
    {
        public int OrderNum { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the max. value in List of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563527/get-the-max-value-in-list-of-objects)

Comment: Try looping through all of the lessons and comparing them with an if statement.

Comment: Simply `Model.Lessons.Max(x=> x.OrderNum)`? Or is Model.Lessons something completely different and more complex then the shown Lesson class and not just a list of instances of that class?

Comment: Thank you i believe these will work I'm just struggling to get it working as i just get more errors

Comment: If you update your question post and include your full code, it is easier for us to point out possible reasons to _why_ you get those errors :)

Comment: My _guess_ now is that `_LessonService.Commit( )` takes an object of type `Lesson` as an input parameter -- is that correct? If so, you would need to find the `Lesson` object with the largest `OrderNum` value (rather than just finding the largest `OrderNum` value). You can do that by using Linq's [`.MaxBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-7.0). (You need to put `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file, if you haven't already.) Then: `var lesson = model.Lessons.MaxBy(x => x.OrderNum);` followed by `await _LessonService.Commit(lesson);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in many ways

```
var searchedLesson = lessons.OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderNum).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
var searchedLesson = lessons.Max(x => x.OrderNum);
```